# Ndepend.API to capture code violations

Tags: ndepend

I want to extract the Code violations like errors,warnings from my C# code using Ndepend API.
Can you please help me in fetching the information.

Thanks.
Sajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post should answer all your questions on this matter:

http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2014/04/29/running-ndepend-rules-through-ndepend-api/